# Create a 1 inch measurement

Tags: paper-folding

This is a follow up to the "[Create a 3 inch measurement](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49253)" puzzle, which got a lot of innovative solutions. 
Using the standard 8.5 x 11 inch paper, can you create a 1 inch measurement only by folding? Again no marking allowed. No ruler either.

One more thing. **I realize that folding the 8.5 inch side three times can get you 1.06 inches. But can you do better than that?** Maybe I was overdoing it, but I think I got it in more than 3 folds.

Comment: new stack proposal:  Paper Folding Golf SE. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution in 4 folds:

> 1. Fold one corner down to the opposite side. We now have a triangle that is 8.5" by 8.5", and a flap below it that is 2.5" by 8".
>  2. Fold the flap up, and call this Flap A. Now unfold the paper and turn it upside down.
>  3-4. Repeat the same steps to get a Flap B.
>  Now, unfold the paper and just fold down Flap A and Flap B. the thin space between the two flaps should have length exactly 1".

This is because

> The flaps are of length 2.5", and when folded up (or down) that is another 2.5"  for a total of 5". If Flap A accounts for 5" and Flap B accounts for another 5" from either side of the 11" length of the paper, the space in between should be 1".

Answer (score 4):

A solution in 3 folds:

> 1. Fold diagonally to get triangle of side length 8.5, leaving 2.5 inches on the 11 inch side uncovered
>  2. Fold the 2.5 inch flap up, leaving 6 inches on the 11 inch side uncovered
>  3. Create a fold at the 6 inch mark on the 11 inch side using the covered part 
>
> Unfold the 2.5 inch fold in order to get a flap of 5 inches which leaves only 1 inch uncovered on the 11 inch side.

Comment: This is an easier, more accurate way of finding a point one inch from the end of the 11" side than I used in my ruler answer to the previous question. As discussed in [my ruler answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49253#49340), another nine pinches allow creating a ruler with one pinch every inch.

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses the first six steps from my [ruler answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49253#49340) to the previous question.  (LliwTelracs' answer is a better way of finding the same point.)

> The labels are optional; they serve only to uniquely identify the points and creases.
>  Label the ends of a short side NW and NE.
>  Label the corresponding ends of the other short side SW and SE.
>  Clockwise from the top right, the points are NE, SE, SW, and NW.
>  1. Crease between NW and SE.  Unfold.
>  2. Pinch a mark halfway between NE and SE.  This mark is point $1/2$.
>  3. Crease between SW and $1/2$.  Unfold.  Where this crease crosses NW-SE is point $1/3$.
>  4. Fold the raw edge SW-SE to lie on point $1/3$, such that raw corner SW lies along the NW-SW raw edge, and raw corner SE lies along the NE-SE raw edge.  Pinch a mark at the NE-SE raw edge end of the fold.  Unfold.  This mark is point $1/6$.
>  5. Fold the raw edge SW-SE so that point SE lies on point $1/6$, and point SW lies along the NW-SW raw edge.  Pinch a mark where the NW-SE crease crosses the new fold.  Unfold.  This mark is point $1/12$.
>  6. Crease from point SW through point $1/12$ to raw edge NE-SE.  Unfold.  The NE-SE end of this crease is point $1/11$.

With another 9 pinches, it is possible to turn the 11" side of the paper into a ruler with one pinch every inch.

Answer (score 0):

Only 2, but if you want to "mark it on side", you need 3.

> [image: Demonstration]
>
>  It's not exactly 1, but something like 1.01077, because it's possible that [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) rounded it somewhere.
>  Edit: According to other posts - this is only 2 folds.

Comment: What are the references for the creases?